# Is it possible to access a variable from a string?

Tags: c++

What I want to do: For example I have this:

```
    int some_random_name;
    string str="some_random_name";
```

So can I access `int` variable using just `str` string?

Sorry if my question is stupid and weird;

Comment: If you want to create a string with the value of your `int` then `string str = std::to_string(some_random_name);`. If instead you want to use that string to lookup the variable later, no you cannot do that, C++ does not support reflection, you'd have to do something like make a `map` of your variable names to their values, which I would strongly discourage as that is generally a code smell

Comment: A variable is a name for a memory location. It exists only in the source code. When the source code is compiled, any reference to the variable is replaced with the address of the memory location it names. The variable name does not exist in the compiled code.

Comment: That's not what you want to do; it's an XY problem. What are you **actually** trying to do?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: An XY problem solved by Java (although not for variables at function scope). Perhaps though Java is itself a solution to an XY problem.

Comment: @Bathsheba For every problem Java solves, it introduces a few. It's just marginally better than regex at that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Amen to that. My favourite: cached Integer references.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, I am trying to create Turing Machine simulator, where state has commands like "1RQ2", so I thought I could take "Q2" part and use it to run Q2 state execution. Something like `q_exe(Q2);` Following my idea, I could take last 2 characters from the command and use it as the name of other variable. But, how @axiac said, it's not possible. Thank you )

Comment: @AWRDev. yeah, you absolutely don't need to use *actual* variables for that, a `map` like people have been suggesting will work way better for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to create Turing Machine simulator, where state has commands like "1RQ2", so I thought I could take "Q2" part and use it to run Q2 state execution. Something like q_exe(Q2);

The first observation to make is that you don't have to store your data in actual named variables. If you use a `map<string, int>`, the whole question becomes pretty easy.

There's absolutely no need for pointers of any kind with this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly not, you are after a concept called *reflection*, and C++ does not support that (which allows it to compile out all variable names).

One approach would be to maintain a `std::map` keyed by a `std::string`, where the values are pointers to the variables you want to access, or perhaps even the values themselves.

Comment: What about macros?

Answer (score -2):

You may use a map.

```
int some_random_name = 3;
std::string str="some_random_name";
std::map<std::string, int*> map;
map[str] = &some_random_name;

std::cout << *(map[str]); // print 3
*(map[str]) = 5;
std::cout << *(map[str]); // print 5
some_random_name = 8;
std::cout << *(map[str]); // print 8
```

You may also use macro such as:

```
#define REGISTER_VARNAME(var) map[#var] = &var
```

Comment: No, you might not use a macro for that. Not because it's impossible, but because it's horrendous. Also the pointers are unnecessary here. The usecase in the comments would do perfectly well with just values.

Comment: The macro ensure the registred key match the variable, it has it's advantages. If you find it horrendous do not use it. And no, "just values" do not works with my exemple because of the third print.